# ElasticSearch Suggest current or next word

Tags: elasticsearch, autosuggest, elasticsearch-8

I have many queries like:

```
"iphone 10"
"iphone 10 case"
"iphone 11"
"iphqqq"
```

I would like to autosuggest the current or next word (prefix-like manner is ok).
For example (input -> [outputs]):

```
"iph" -> ["iphone", "iphqqq"] ("iphone" is present only once in suggests)
"iphone” -> ["10", "11"]
"iphone 1” -> ["10", "11"]
"iphone 10" -> ["case"]
"10" -> [] (since there are no queries that start with "10")
"case" -> []
```

I looked towards the completion-suggester, but I didn’t understand whether it was possible to implement the removal of duplicates in suggests and how exactly to implement the output of only the current or next word.

It won’t be a problem for me to do pre-processing of queries or post-processing of outputs if the problem cannot be completely solved using elasticsearch alone.

elasticsearch version: 8.10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ElasticSearch is not suitable for this kind of application**. ElasticSearch uses vector search to output a similar query according to similarity metric. It transforms a query into an embedding (which is vector in a form of a list of numerical values), which is then compared to other existing queries.

It would be possible to implement it with ElasticSearch if there was a similarity metric like `S(q1, q2)`: if `q1` is a substring of `q2` then `q1` is similar to `q2`. But this similarity metric doesn't make sense, it's binary not numerical. Similarity metrics used in ElasticSearch include Euclidean (L2 norm) and cosine.

To solve your problem efficiently, **you can use [tree trie](https://medium.com/guidona-softpedia/understanding-trie-data-structure-39e7652114d5)**.